# Can't get the Context where is define in the super class

Tags: java, android

I have a super class:

```
public abstract class AsyncRequest {
  private Context context;
  public AsyncRequest(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
  }
  public Context getContext() {
    return this.context;
  }
  protected abstract String getHost();
}
```

And two sub class:

```
public abstract class IRequest extends AsyncRequest{
  IRequest(Context context) {
    super(context);
  }
  @Override
  public String getHost() {
    return getHostFromSharedPreferences();
  }
  private String getHostFromSharedPreferences(){
    SharedPreferences preferences = ((Activity) getContext()).getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    return preferences.getString(IPresenter.SP_HOST,"");
  }
}

public class LoginRequest extends IRequest{
   public LoginRequest(Context context, String name, String password) {
     super(context);
   }
}
```

when I init a `LoginRequest`, and I use `getContext()` to get the context in `IRequest`,I get `NullPointerException`.

I don't know why,do someoneelse know?

Comment: It would help to post a code snippet showing where you try to use these classes, as well as a stack trace of the exception from logcat.

Comment: The context you passed was null. You need to show more code. A [mcve]

Comment: You may need to pass in the context as a parameter to `getHostFromSharedPreferences` method .

Comment: If all you call is getContext() and not getContex().someFunc(), then your request object is null.

Answer (score 1):

Make it sure when you instantiate **LoginRequest** you are sending **non null** **Context** as argument
    LoginRequest(Context context, String name, String password)

Comment: I have see the context,it's null when I use `getContext` in `LoginRequest`,but in the `IRequest` it's null

Answer (score 1):

```
Class A
{
int x;
A(int x)
{
this.x=x;
}
X getX()
{
return this.x;
}
}
```

What value are you passing to variable "x" here ?
In your case it is context.
To get the context of a class in android, there is always an inbuilt getApplicationContext() method.
My suggestion is,

```
Class A
{
Context context;
onCreate Method Block 
{
....................
....................
context=getApplicationContext();
}
}
```

Now use this context variable wherever inside your class, it wouldn't throw null pointer exception.

Answer (score 0):

I just know the casue to problem right now.

As you see,I have init a `LoginRequest` with the constructor with `context`,of course the `context` is null,and the method `getContext()` in the `AsyncRequest` I try to invoke using `loginRequest.getContex()` will get an object which is `not null`.But the issue is that where I try to invoke the method `getContext()` is in the `IRequest`,which means that `iRequest.getContext()`,but I did't init the `iRequest`,`So this is the cause!`.

The problem teachs me that you should know the really object which invokes the method.I simply think that because the `LoginRequest` extends `IRequest`,when I init `LoginRequest`,I init `IRequest`,which is a bad idea you need to give up.

Because I need to invoke the same code in the Object which extends `IRequest`,so I invoke the code in `IRequest`,but I can't get the `context` in `IRequest`.There is one of the ways to solve the problem:

I create a class named `App` and let it extends `Application`,in this class it has one attribute `public static Context context`,and in the `onCreate` method I init the context.Because `App` is alive in the whole android lifecycle,so I can get it anywhere.Just use `App.context`.

Finally,Thanks everybody try to solve my problem.

Answer (score -1):

Change this:

```
public AsyncRequest(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
}
```

...to this:

```
public AsyncRequest(@NonNull Context context) {
    // noinspection ConstantConditions - public API
    if(context == null) {
        throw new NullPointerException();
    }
    this.context = context;
}
```

You'll likely find that you're calling the constructor with a null `Context`.  The constructor is responsible for ensuring that the object's fields are valid, so it's important to check for invalid arguments.

Comment: Doesn't the annotation defeat the purpose of the null check? Also passing a null value to a constructor is valid in some cases.

Comment: Violating the annotation is only a warning by default, so for accessible methods I like to add the explicit check to make it fail-fast.

Comment: Well, still, throwing a NPE to find another NPE seems pointless.

Comment: @cricket_007 My reasoning is that if it's thrown from the constructor, the consumer of the API will immediately know exactly what they did wrong and where.  The annotation should tell them this, but judging by the projects I've worked on, a frightful number of programmers ignore compiler warnings.

Comment: I debug it,the context is not null,but use `getContext()`,get null.